# Getting Java Binding for Dbus to Run on Android

Tags: java, android, dbus

Has anyone succeeded in running the Java bindings for dbus on Android? All indications point at dbus already running as a process within the Android OS, but there is no official access point for them through the Java interface.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't do this unless you're talking about your own bus talking to things you control.  There's no guarantee that dbus will be available.  According to the android mailing list, [it's just an implementation detail that dbus is around at all, it's not guaranteed to be there, and might not be there in the future.](http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/24a98bb7c0b44c58/001a67a1ee80779e)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [dbus-java](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/)  from the freedesktop project. I don't know if it works on android tough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'd given that a try, but it requires a JNI implementation of Unix sockets to run. That requires pushing a C library onto Android, which I am not quite sure how to do. I've seen that pushing simple programs is possible, but I haven't seen a full library pushed. Or perhaps I'm just not runinng the make properly.

Comment: You can use TCP instead of unix-sockets, and then you have pure Java library

Comment: you'd need to modify the dbus library.  There's nothing like a configuration option to build without unix sockets.

Comment: Android has always supported Unix domain sockets (at least to some degree) in Java via the LocalSocket class.